# Preferred way to handle text? Typography vs Box vs div/span

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Been using React with Material UI for a while, but still unsure how to handle text on a page.  Should I wrap it with Typography?  Should I do a Box, span, or div?  Is there any real difference between the options?  How are others handling this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd generally use a Typography component if I want to leverage the styles in my Material-UI theme (or the default theme). This helps keep the app looking consistent, and makes it super-easy to change a font, size, weight, etc across the whole app. Otherwise, for something with unique styling, a plain div or span will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Box component can also be used as a wrapper for your Typography, for example to position & override theme styles at the same time.  Rendering a Box component will create a new div on the DOM by default and props are passed down to the Children.

Box is used below for positioning, and overrides the colour prop of all the child headers from black to blue. The advantage is I don't have to override each Typography component and the [Box component supports all system props](https://mui.com/system/properties/) so I could also be overriding things like borders, background colours, etc.

```
<Box style={{color: 'blue', display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column noWrap'}}>
  <Typography variant='h1'> 
    This h1 will now be blue
  </Typography>
  <Typography style={{alignSelf: 'center'}} variant='h2'>
    This h2 is blue and centered
  </Typography>
  <Typography style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}} variant='h3'>
    This h3 is blue and right aligned
  </Typography>
</Box>
```